# Talend convert to bigdecimal from string

Tags: java, date, timestamp, talend, impala

I am reading a text file which has a field in Timestamp in this format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

I want to be able to convert it to a field in Impala as BigInt and should like yyyMMddHHmmss in Java.
Following this link:
[Java Timestamp to BigInt for Impala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282037/java-timestamp-to-bigint-for-impala)

I use the talend methods for conversion and do this:

```
TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss",TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row5.StopTime))
```

Here StopTime is my timestamp.  I first parse it to a Date format, then to a format it to the required format. I have a string.

The impala table that has DBType BigInt has JavaType BigDecimal.

How do I convert the string I have to a BigDecimal.  Right not the DBtypesof schemas don't match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure that a BIGINT is just a Long, no?

Comment: I thought so.  If I leave it as long, i get an error saying the DBtype does not match :(

Comment: An error or a warning? If it's just a warning you can ignore it and assume that Talend have set the data type mapping wrong for the component. I get that for a few things like when I want to pull a datetime field from a database as a string rather than a date.

Comment: it was a warning.  I tried to ignore it but then it doesnt finish the process and stops the further components too. It shows it is copying the rows into the database, but eventually after a very long, it says the schema in the input link does not match.  So I tried to import schema from the dbconnection and it mentioned that type is Bigdecimal and so this workaround of changing the variable to BigDecimal.

Comment: I think it is a import issue? I tried using the full name java.math.BigDecimal it says java.math.BigDecimal cannot be resolved into a type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you just want to instantiate a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) from a `String`, in which case:

```
new BigDecimal(TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                        TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row5.StopTime)))
```

Comment: I do the same thing and I get an error saying BigDecimal cannot be resolved into a type

Comment: You'll need to post more detail than that. BigDecimal is part of the core API, there shouldn't be any issue resolving it.